# Derived classes and function hiding

Tags: c++

Consider the following example:

```
class A {
    public:
    int foo() { return 1; }
    int bar() { return foo(); }
};

class B : public A {
    int foo() { return 2; }
};

int main() {
    auto b = B();
    return b.bar();
}
```

Why does `main()` return 1 insted of 2? Is `foo()` not the most visible function for `B`? Does there exist some `override`-feature for non-virtual classes to completely replace a function in every call? I know of CRTP, but it is quite verbose in this simple case.

Comment: Because that's how C++ works? The equivalent Java code would return 2, of course, but C++ is not Java. A function needs to be an explicit `virtual` function in order to work the way you expect it to work.

Comment: methods in c++ won't be overridden unless you explicitly marked it with `virtual` keyword

Comment: Is there a good reason why this feature is restricted to ```virtual``` classes? Is this not an independant concept?

Comment: It's a performance reason. Java-style virtual dispatch requires waiting until runtime to know which function to call. In C++, it can figure out which function will be called at compile time based on the type of the calling object. If you want the slower polymorphic behavior, you have to explicitly opt into it.

Comment: see: https://pabloariasal.github.io/2017/06/10/understanding-virtual-tables/

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "`virtual` classes". Member functions could be virtual, not classes. Also, what concept do you feel is independent from what other concept?

Comment: _"Because that's how C++ works?"_ No need to be patronising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is what `virtual` is for!**

The function you're calling, `A::bar()`, doesn't know that the full object is a `B`. It only knows the `A` context. You can also think of it as doing a call to  `this->foo()`, where `this` is an `A*` (because it is).

If `foo` were `virtual`, the call would work as you expect: looking up the most-derived type at runtime and using that instead.

Polymorphism isn't an "independent concept" from this; it's literally *this* concept.

Comment: Isn't ```virtual``` referring to runtime polymorphism? In my example there is nothing decided at runtime.

Comment: @Henk How come? If you're saying that because the program is small, and the compiler has all the information in front of it to know that the object is a `B`, well that's true it does.... (and indeed it may not need a vtable lookup in reality!) but that's not really relevant and you could say the same thing about other examples of polymorphism. The language is designed such that you have to "turn on" this behaviour with `virtual`. ‍♂️

Comment: Someone told me so. So I should think of a derived class not as copying all the data, but instead also having a pointer to the base class in addition to the new methods provided by the derived class?

Comment: @Henk I probably wouldn't phrase it that way... but essentially yes. When you invoke a member function through an expression of type `T`, the "static type" of the object in that context is `T`, so only member functions of actually `T` (or its bases) are found. You need polymorphism to "magically" invoke the function in more derived classes instead. There's no base pointer "stored" anywhere: the code is in the class `A`, so `this` being an `A*` is just inherent.

Comment: @Henk This is an important property. Otherwise you could not design a class `A` with dependable semantics: you'd _always_ be wondering whether someone had swapped out your behaviour with some overridden version. This way, you have to _turn that on_ with `virtual`, saying, okay, you can override this if you like.

Comment: But that would only happen within the someone itself, so it could figure out the right calls by itself.

Comment: @Henk No, the base class would be unaware of all of this. When you're writing code in the base class, by default you should only consider _that class_. Pretend derived classes don't exist, and that therefore any instance cannot be of such a derived class. It's a basic abstraction. An `A` is an `A`, no matter whether there's a larger `B` at work around it. Then, if you write `virtual` in your base design, you're accepting the possibility that it could be so (though a derived class should still take steps not to fundamentally alter the semantics), but that's an extra thing, called polymorphism.

Comment: In other words, a base class _shouldn't need to care_ about any derivations. It's a black box. That's how we write stable designs that have predictable and provable behaviours, and how we can allow ourselves to extend those designs (via inheritance) without absolute chaos.

Comment: I guess the flaw in my thinking is that the derived class does not necessaraly have full information of the base class and can therefore not reimplement everything itself.

Comment: No, the derived class has complete information on the base class. But we don't _want_ it to reimplement everything itself. The base class has no information on the derived class, and when you're in a member function of the base, it's the base class's information that you are working with. I recommend a good book on OO theory!

Answer (score 1):

The definition of `class A` is equivalent to: (see this-pointer)

```
class A {
    public:
    int foo() { return 1; }
    int bar() { return this->foo(); }
};
```

During the linking, `bar` uses the definition of `foo` in `class A`.

Below is a version delivering the result you expect:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A {
    public:
    int foo() { return 2; }
};

class B : public A {
    
    public:
    int foo() { return 1; }
    int bar1() { return foo(); }
    int bar2() { return A::foo(); }
};

int main() {
    auto b = B();
    std::cout<<b.bar1()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<b.bar2()<<std::endl;
}


Output:
1
2
```